# I need to run a python script in IDLE from a BAT file

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, ipython, python-idle

I have a python script which creates some images. The script runs in Ipython IDLE as expected, however then I call IDLE from the cmd line, and include the name of the script, the script loads but does not execute. If I hit F5(run Module) then the program runs, but I wonder if it is possible to make the script run without having to press F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not run the script directly from the command line using "python script_file.py" in your command line?

Comment: When I try that, I get a series of errors related to matplotlib.pyplot and then finally an ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: GOT IT, I am now using the WinPython interpreter, and the script does run  from the command line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you can se here https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html#command-line-usage, you can try with:

```
idle -r yourscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you totally sure thet your script needs to be run from IDLE?
You can run it directly with your Python interpreter like this:

```
С:\<path_to_your_python_interpreter> <path_to your_script>
```

Comment: the script calls several graphics and numeric packages to create charts and I am using a QT version of IDLE which has these packages available. Running from straight python interpreter generates numerous errors and I was hoping for way to run in IDLE from a BAT file since it does run there.